# find another META-INF/persistence.xml

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a problem:
My project search persistence.xml in another directory

code

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.psc.repository", "com.psc.export.itconfig.repositories"},
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("psc_test");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    AuditorAware auditorAware() {
        return (AuditorAware<String>) () -> {
            final String userName = Optional.ofNullable(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest())
                    .map(request -> Optional.ofNullable(request.getUserPrincipal())
                            .map(principal -> principal.getName())
                            .orElse(request.getRemoteUser()))
                    .orElse(AppData.getAppData().getCurrentUser());

            return userName;
        };
    }
}
```

path of class above is test\java\configurations\JpaTestConfig.java

there is my xml file in path test\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml

When i run test it refer to another persistence.xml in absolutely different package of my project. How to fix it? In another persistence.xml even doesn't exist unit (psc_test)

test class

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) //@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class) @WebAppConfiguration @ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaTestConfig.class, ServicesConfig.class, restService.com.websystique.springmvc.configuration.RestConfig.class}) public class BranchControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;



        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();    }

        @Test
        public void getFoo() throws Exception {    /*  code here */
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Some times ambiguity occurs... for testing purpose create a new workspace and keeping the project that you want to test.Dont keep unnecessary project if it works then its good or otherwise its the problem with the path.
Or Else.. you can change the persistence name and check whether it still pointing the another persistence.xml or not.

Comment: thanks for answer!!

Yes. it is mapping on another package and its persistemse.xml( may it will be usefull: my model ( @Entity classes lie in this package)